# anchor div for email address in flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to use an anchor tag for an email hyperlink inside of a container using a flexbox. All of the information on the page is displaying correctly, including an image, but the email is positioning itself on the top right hand corner of the screen. I read that a new div tag in a flexbox container can essentially begin a new flexbox, which is what appears to be happening. Can anyone advise?

```
'''

{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}  
  {% if messages %}  
    {% for message in messages %}  
      <p>{{ message }}</p>  
    {% endfor %}  
  {% endif %}  
{%endwith%}

<h2 style = "text-align: center;">ABOUT</h2>

<style>
div.container {
    align-content: flex-start;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    flex-wrap: no-wrap; 
  }

  div.anchor{
  position: relative;
 }

div.container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-right-width: 20px;
  border-right-color: solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

img{
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-right: 20px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
 


</style>


<body>


<div class="container">

  <p>
    <a target="_blank" href="static/about.jpg"></a>
      <img src="../static/about.jpg" alt="aboutpic" width="200" height="100">
    </a>
  </p>
blah blah blah</br>
</br>
blah blah blah</br>
</br>
 

blah blah blah </br>
</br>
blah blah blah </br>
</br>
For appointments please contact blah blah blah directly at:</br>
</br>
Phone: blah blah blah</br>
</br>
Email:<div class="anchor"><a href="mailto:blah blah blah@gmail.com"> blah blah blah.com</a>
</div> 
</div>
</body>
{% endblock %}
'''
```

Comment: Try to use table format instead of div for email body table format is better.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

added `flex-direction: column;` to `div.container`

```css
div.container {
    align-content: flex-start;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    flex-wrap: no-wrap; 
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  div.anchor{
  position: relative;
 }

div.container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-right-width: 20px;
  border-right-color: solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

img{
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-right: 20px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

```html
<h2 style = "text-align: center;">ABOUT</h2>

<body>


<div class="container">

  <p>
    <a target="_blank" href="static/about.jpg"></a>
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1453728013993-6d66e9c9123a?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8dmlld3xlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" alt="aboutpic" width="200" height="100">
    </a>
  </p>
blah blah blah</br>
</br>
blah blah blah</br>
</br>
 

blah blah blah </br>
</br>
blah blah blah </br>
</br>
For appointments please contact blah blah blah directly at:</br>
</br>
Phone: blah blah blah</br>
</br>
Email:<div class="anchor"><a href="mailto:blah blah blah@gmail.com"> blah blah blah@gmail.com</a>
</div> 
</div>
</body>
```

Also, your HTML is a bit off, try avoiding 
 tags and use border on css to visualize layout

```css
div.container {
    align-content: flex-start;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

.container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-right: 5px solid cyan;
}

img{
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-right: 20px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
p {
border: 2px solid red;
}
.email {
border: 2px solid lime;
}
}
```

```html
<h2 style = "text-align: center;">ABOUT</h2>

<body>


<div class="container">
    <a target="_blank" href="static/about.jpg"></a>
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1453728013993-6d66e9c9123a?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8dmlld3xlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" alt="aboutpic" width="200" height="100">
  </a>
  <p>blah blah blah</p>
  <p>blah blah blah</p>

  <p>blah blah blah</p>

  <p>blah blah blah</p>
  <p>
  For appointments please contact blah blah blah directly at:
  </p>
  <p>Phone: blah blah blah</p>
  <div class="email">
  Email:<a href="mailto:blah blah blah@gmail.com"> blah blah blah@gmail.com</a>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

> I would also advise you to read or watch a 100 second video about flex, this one is really good https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K74l26pE4YA

Comment: First of all, thank you for taking your time on this, but unfortunately not quite what I am looking for. I had the image to the left of most of my content originally, it was extremely large so even after updating max-width to 25%, the pic is still above my main content. I like the layout with the flex-direction row, but it would move the email hyperlink way out of alignment. Also interesting, is now the email is below the "Email:" text, not to the right of it.

Comment: @White_Homme try using flex 1 and wrapping all the P tags inside one div, this will share the space equally between the sections